# Display #VAL of point when mouse moves over in Line Graph (Mschart)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-3.5, tooltip, mschart

There is not much documentation on Mscharts in general for C# in Visual Studio 2008. I have researched alot for solutions but nothing seems to work! When the user hovers over the line at a data point, the value of that particular point should be displayed and when lost focus should disappear. I understand the best way to do this, I think, is to add Tooltips to my chart, but my problem is actually getting the value from a data point. The chart looks like this at the moment with just hard-coded data for testing but will be getting round to importing the data from a file:

[image]

*_Note: I do realise the lines are not realistic - not for my project anyway. It's just for testing. When I have completed the project, there will be several data points._*

### Adding Series and Data Points:

```
var sv = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series("1");
sv.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
sv.Points.Add(new DataPoint(201, 10));
sv.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 11));
sv.YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
chart1.Series.Add(sv);

var ov = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series("2");
ov.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
ov.Points.Add(new DataPoint(201, 25));
ov.Points.Add(new DataPoint(8, 3));
ov.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
chart1.Series.Add(ov);

var oc = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series("3");
oc.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
oc.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
oc.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 5));
oc.Points.Add(new DataPoint(190, 90));
oc.Points.Add(new DataPoint(200, 90));
chart1.Series.Add(oc);

var sn = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series("4");
sn.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
sn.Points.Add(new DataPoint(9, 30));
sn.Points.Add(new DataPoint(150, 28));
sn.XAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
chart1.Series.Add(sn);
```

### Modifying Graph:

```
Chart_Line.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = Chart_Line.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = Chart_Line.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri Light", 8);
Chart_Line.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
Chart_Line.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 201;
Chart_Line.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 15;

Chart_Line.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 140;
Chart_Line.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 20;
Chart_Line.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;

Chart_Line.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Maximum = 30;
Chart_Line.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Interval = 5;
Chart_Line.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Minimum = 0;

Chart_Line.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
Chart_Line.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
Chart_Line.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
```

### MouseMove Event:

```
private void Chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult result = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);

    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Interval = 0;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(p, true);
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.LineColor = Color.Crimson;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.LineWidth = 1;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SetCursorPixelPosition(p, true);
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.LineColor = Color.Crimson;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.LineWidth = 1;
}
```

I'm not sure how to go about automatically creating tooltips for datapoints, activating when mouse is hovering over and then removing it. The cursor lines work fine!

Comment: you want tooltip like tooltip thing?.

Comment: That doesn't make sense? Yes, I would like a tooltip as specified above.

Comment: Something like `serie.ToolTip = "X:#VALX  Y:#VALY";` ?

Comment: I tried that and doesn't work... tried: chart1.Series[0].ToolTip = "#VAL"; (simple test) too but again, doesn't work at all for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier than I first thought :) Populating the graph was pretty complex, that is most likely why I got so confused!

```
string info = "Value: " + "#VAL{N2}" + "\n" + "Average: " + "#AVG{N2}" + "\n" + "Minimum: " + "#MIN{N2}" + "\n" + "Maximum: " + "#MAX{N2}" + "\n"
            + "First: " + "#FIRST{N2}" + "\n" + "Last: " + "#LAST{N2}";

Chart1.Series[0].ToolTip = "Series name..." + "\n" + info;
Chart1.Series[1].ToolTip = "Series name2..." + "\n" + info;
Chart1.Series[2].ToolTip = "Series name3..." + "\n" + info;

private void Chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult result = Chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);

    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Interval = 0;
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(p, true);
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SetCursorPixelPosition(p, true);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can this be done in the web version of ms charts? I don't see this event listed.

Answer (score 0):

To provide the answer for your question.

```
chart1.Series[0].Points[n].ToolTip = "#VALX";
```

Tried and tested with a line chart.

Answer (score 0):

The one marked as the solution is correct but is not so clear and I would like to add details.

When you populate the graph, after that, you should construct the String `info` variable that has all the pretty information an Analyst like me will value.

What are those symbols like `VAL{N2}`?
Those symbols have a different meaning which been [explained by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd456687(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

```cs
string info = "Value: " + "#VAL{N2}" + "\n" + "Average: " + "#AVG{N2}" + "\n" + "Minimum: " + "#MIN{N2}" + "\n" + "Maximum: " + "#MAX{N2}" + "\n"
            + "First: " + "#FIRST{N2}" + "\n" + "Last: " + "#LAST{N2}";

Grafico.Series["valores"].ToolTip = "Detalles..." + "\n" + info;
Grafico.Series["valores2"].ToolTip = "Detalles..." + "\n" + info;
```

Where `valores` and `valores2` are different graphs.

Then add a procedure that give instructions about the mouse movement over the graph and it should work.

```cs
private void Grafico_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult result = Grafico.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);    
    System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);

    Grafico.ChartAreas["valores"].CursorX.Interval = 0;
    Grafico.ChartAreas["valores2"].CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(p, true);    
}
```